# How to run a while loop while x or greater not in list in python?

Tags: python, while-loop

I want to run a while loop for as long as there is any value in my list that is greater than 3.

so for example:

```
while 3 or greater not in list:
    run loop
```

Is there any trick to achieve this without having to create another loop to check for this?

Thanks

EDIT:

thanks for the suggetions. I was actually checking in a 2D numpy array. I ended up making it like this:

```
tilemap = np.zeros((mapheight, mapwidth), dtype = np.int)

while max(tilemap.ravel()) > 3:
    run loop
```

Comment: Make sure you tag your question with a programming language. Otherwise it's hard to give you a specific response. Have you tried looking at the basic tutorials for that language?

Comment: I just noticed too, thanks. And I looked around but I was not able to find anything.

Comment: have you considered using the built-in [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for something along these lines:

```
while any(i >= 3 for i in l):
    # Do something
```

For example:

```
l = [4, 6, 2, 1, 0, 7, 9]
while any(i >= 3 for i in l):
    l.remove(max(l))
print(l)
```

Which leaves

```
[2, 1, 0]
```